# OpenXML library - Get the location of a cell in the worksheet (eg: A4)

Tags: indexing, merge, spreadsheet, openxml

Hi can someone please help me on how to retrieve the location of a cell (for example: A4) because I want to merge them.

I have a 2 cells:

```
    cell1 = GenerateCell();
    cell2 = GenerateCell();

    // Get cell locations
    cell1Loc = ...
    cell2Loc = ...

    Merge(cell1Loc, cell2Loc);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. Are you generating a spreadsheet from scratch? Or do you want to parse and read information from an existing xlsx file?

Comment: I've generated the spreadsheet from scratch which is reading from a HTML table and creating the content onto a spreadsheet. Some of these <td></td>'s have colspans. What I want to do is merge these cells, I can do that part but I need the location of the first and last cell

Comment: I'd really recommend using the *Document Reflector* included in the SDK. Create and format the Excel spreadsheet as desired using Excel, then open the document using the reflector. It will show you exactly how to achieve the desired formatting using code.